# Linux: copy a list of file whose name suffix is listed in a txt file from one directory to another

Tags: xubuntu, cp

I want to copy all the files that contain in their name the strings that are listed in a .txt file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are listed in the text file one per line, you can run `xargs` with argument-file option (`-a`) and `cp *"{}"*`. (`{}` is the placeholder for the string in each line.

```
cd /path/to/original_folder
xargs -a strings.txt -I{} bash -c 'cp *"{}"* /somewhere/else'
```

Comment: Where do I have to specify the original folder?

Comment: Actually the ones are listed are part of directory names and I have to recursevely copy subdirectory and files in them..does this command do this?

Comment: No, it won't do that. My answer is doing what you have asked in the question. Please edit your question and add **all** details ...